# Developing and maintaining Magento extension

Tags: svn, magento, netbeans

I'm developing some Magento extensions then I have had some notices relating to the development processes. So I just look for some tips/tricks from all of you to get know the best way to maintain Magento extension.

Actually, I use Netbeans, SVN and Ubuntu as my main development environment. This is the process I have applied:

- Creating/Developing extension on Netbeans
- Exporting extension to other directory while keeping theirs full path *(so app/etc. or skin/etc.)*
- Copy this exported file into brand new / clean magento site to test it
- If everything is ok, I compress this exported directory to .zip or .gz file.

### So these are my questions

1. Netbeans does not allow neither exporting multiple files at the same time nor exporting full path to files or directories. So I had to create directories and export files manually. The pity is that files are everywhere *(eg. in app/code/local, app/design/adminhtml, app/design/frontend, skin/adminhtml, skin/frontend, etc.)*. So, **is there easier way to do this with some mouse clicks?**
2. Testing extension on clean installed magento site. In this step, if there is a bug, I do the modification on this testing site then repeat manually these changes on my dev version. **Is there an easier way to do the tests on older version or Magento?**

If some of you have got experience in these issues, please give me some advices.

Thanks,

[ntuan16](http://blog.veev.vn)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the modman script which makes managing magento modules much easier: https://github.com/colinmollenhour

Comment: +1 for modman.  We do pretty much the same as the OP asked, develop extensions in a separate repo (although it's git for us), then use modman to link it into a test site.  Works like a charm.  Having common extensions in separate repos makes reuse of extensions much easier.

Comment: Thanks Drew and Jim. Yours answers are very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use Aptana + GIT + OSX.

Firstly, as you mentioned, some clean Magento sites varying different versions are quite important for our development. So setting up Magento site + sample data automatically is necessary.

Then, I initialize a git repository and start to develop. (Aptana have full support for GIT).

And here you are going to have two options to distribute your newly developed extension into Magento site.

- Make symbolic link to the magento site. Once done, every modification just need to refresh the broswer.
- Write a script to copy the code to the Magento directory. (My choice)

All the above things can be done in the terminal.

BTW, you can try the unit test for the Magento. It is more suitable for a big development group.

Comment: Colin Mollenhour's modman tool can make managing those symlinks pretty painless.  Also, if you haven't seen it before, there's a git repo maintained at https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror with most of the recent Magento versions tagged.  This makes switching between Magento versions as simple as checking out a tag new tag in git.  Great for testing.